# Compare values in a Json File using Python

Tags: python, json

I want a python script that take a json file (file.json), and compare the values of the keys

```
"From",

"To",

"Source",

"Destination",

"Service"
```

If all the values are the same then it will display the value of their "ID".

Example:

```
[
{

    "ID": "1",

    "Name": "Rule A",

    "From": "SideD  SideB",

    "To": SideA SideC",

    "Source": "rexA rexB",

    "Destination": "proxy gr amz calc",

    "Schedule": "always",

    "Service": "SSH",

    "Action": "ACCEPT"

  },

  {

    "ID": "4",

    "Name": "Rule B",

    "From": "SideA  SideC",

    "To": "SideB  SideA",

    "Source": "amznA  amznB amznC",

    "Destination": "Reseau Lab Optik",

    "Schedule": "always",

    "Service": "Snmp telnet",

    "Action": "ACCEPT"

  },

  {

    "ID": "6",

    "Name": "Rule C",

   "From": "SideD SideA",

    "To": "SideA  SideB",

    "Source": "rexB",

    "Destination": "proxy gr",

    "Schedule": "no",

    "Service": "SSH",

    "Action": "ACCEPT"

  }

]
```

For this situation, the script will show "ID": 1 and 6, because the keys "From", "To","Source" and "Destination" have at least one same value.

Also put them in a csv file showing the values of the "ID" and alle the rest of the keys and values.

```
 import pandas as pd
 from pprint import pprint as prt

 with open('file.json') as f:
    data = pd.read_json(f)
    ids = data["From"]
    datas = data[ids.isin(ids[ids.duplicated()])].sort_values("ID")
    prt(datas)
```

Comment: What is your question?   What does "If all the values are the same" mean?

Answer (score 0):

**IDs only - any one of 4 column match**:

You can check each item and each one of four target columns and add matches to a list. There are some precautions needed to make sure repeated matches are not reported which are explained in the comments.

```py
import pandas as pd

with open('file2.json') as f:
    data = pd.read_json(f)

# Specify columns to check
cols = ["From", "To", "Source", "Destination"]

# Set ID as index for ease of use
data = data.set_index('ID')

# Emply series to store the matches where index is ID
matches = pd.Series(index=data.index, dtype=object)

# Go through each item
for item_row_num, item_id in enumerate(data.index): 
    
    # Empty list to store matches with current item
    item_matching_ids = []
    
    # Check each column
    for col in cols:
        # If there are any matching IDs with current item add them list
        # We will check only after current row `data.index[item_row_num:]` so
        # for example if [1,6] is detected, it will not be detected again later as [6,1]
        check_result = data.loc[data.index[item_row_num:], col].duplicated()

        if check_result.any():
                item_matching_ids += list(check_result[check_result].index)
            
    # Use set to ensure matching IDs are not repeated
    # This can happen because multiple columns are checked seprately
    matches.loc[item_id] = set(item_matching_ids)

# Only keep item IDs with at least one match
matches = matches[matches.str.len()>0]

# Save matches to CSV
matches.to_csv('output.csv')
```

CSV output:

```
ID  0
1   {6}
```

---

**All values - all columns should match:**

Since you want to write the values to a CSV file, you can use pandas `groupby` where the aggregate function keeps the first occurence for each column except for ID where it stores the list of matching entries.

```py
import pandas as pd

with open('file.json') as f:
    data = pd.read_json(f)

# Make a dictionary where keys are column names
# and values are all 'first' except for ID where value is list
agg_dict = dict.fromkeys(data.columns, 'first')
agg_dict['ID'] = list

# Group rows by desired columns and apply the aggregation
output = data.groupby(["From", "To", "Source", "Destination", "Service"]).agg(agg_dict)

# Write to CSV file ignoring pandas generated index
output.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Output CSV file opened in excel:
[image: output csv file]

---

**IDs only - all columns should match:**

You can use pandas `groupby` which groups rows according to given columns and then get list of the IDs of grouped rows:

```
with open('file.json') as f:
    data = pd.read_json(f)
    output = list(
        data.groupby(["From", "To", "Source", "Destination", "Service"])["ID"].agg(list))
```

Output:

```
[[4], [1, 6]]
```

You can further filter the list to items of at least two match:

```
output = [ids for ids in output if len(ids)>1]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply :) I just updated my question, your help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Answer is updated according to your edits. Let me know if it is what you are looking for. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, now the condition is changed:For this time, the script will show "ID": 1 and 6, because the keys "From", "To","Source" and "Destination" have at least one same value (Not all the character in the value). Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see. So even one of the 4 columns matching would be enough. In that case what values should be there for unmatching columns in the CSV file? A list just like ID?

Comment: The 5 columns have to have at least one matche for each ID. The CSV should only show the list of the ID that have the matches. I don't knw if you understand me.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I do. On the comment you said `The CSV should only show the list of the ID that have the matches` but in the question it is said `csv file showing the values of the "ID" and **all** the rest of the keys and values`

Comment: My bad, I mean the CSV have to show only the ID of the one who matches (like the one you show me [1, 6]).

Comment: I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panda.py", line 56, in <module>
    item_matching_ids += list(data.index[data.loc[data.index[item_row_num:], col].duplicated()])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5055, in __getitem__
    result = getitem(key)
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 393 but corresponding boolean dimension is 392

Comment: I have many wrong answer. I think something wrong. Let me explain again. Sorry for that.

Comment: If you look again my example, you will see that in this example we have 3 dictionaries. The 'ID' that have to be shown by the Excel is 1 and 6. Because when we compare the keys ("From", 'To', 'Source', 'Destination', 'Service' and 'Action') for each dictionary, we can see that they have at least one same value. I know my explanation is not really clear. Hope you will help me to achieve this script. Thanks.

Comment: But all three have `Action` of `ACCEPT`, so all three are a match? Maybe an exact example of same value can make it clear. (Name a key and show that values are match only between 1 and 6)

Comment: The first dict (ID = 1) and the last dict(ID=6) have a same value for the key  "From'': "SideD".

Comment: They also have a same value of their keys  "To":"SideA", "Source": "rexB". "Destination" : "proxy" and "Service" : "SSH"